# Why the function gives only two output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: My question image:-]

Why the output is 4 and 4? Isn't it supposed to be 3 and 4?

Comment: You should include the code in your question, not give a link to an image of your code.

Comment: I meant you should include the code as text in the question, not include an image of the code. You can past in the code, highlight it and then click on the braces `{}` button on top of the edit window to include your code and keep it formatted as code, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `for` loop where you read input each time and each time overwrite the variable `num` with that new inout. After the end of the `for` loop `num` contains the last value input Which is `4`.

You then call you `absolute_value()` method on it and save that return (which is `4`) into the variable `n`.

Then you call `print(n)` twice and so print the value that is saved in `n` two times.

If you want to call your `absolute_value()` method on each input and print the return for each input, then those two lines need to be indented so that they are inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move below code to inside the loop

```
n = absolute(num)
print(n)
```